# GNU make not matching % to make multiple targets from one rule

Tags: makefile

I'm having trouble understanding what seems to be a basic `make` behavior, having multiple prerequisites with some common stem be matched by one rule.

I tried reading the [Pattern intro chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) and seem to be misunderstanding some fundamentals.

```
all: prefix-variant1.so prefix-variant2.so

prefix-%.so : %.o
    @echo "variant with prerequisite succeeded"
```

when I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'prefix-variant1.so', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Keep in mind that make allows to have many concurrent pattern/suffix rules. For example, an object file `%.o` can be created by a C compiler from `%.c`, or by C++ compiler from `%.cpp`, or even by Fortran from `%.f` and so on, and so on.

Therefore, a pattern rule is only taken into account if a corresponding prerequisite file exists (or can be built, see [Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html)). In your case it's `variant1.o`. If no such file exists in the current directory, and no other rule is suitable for building it from source, make ignores the rule and says that there's "no rule to make target".

Comment: If none of the pattern prerequisites exist, _and there are no known rules to generate any of the pattern rule's prerequisites_, then make does not  consider it.   Thus, if you had a pattern rule `%.o:%.c ; $(CC)...`, and you had a `variant1.c` file, then make would be smart enough to connect the dots, build `varaint1.o`, and then `prefix-variant1.so`.   But because `variant1.o` does not exist, and make does not know how to build it, you're getting your error.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry You're right, thank you. I was a bit careless. In make in 99% cases saying "exists" must be expanded to "exists or can be built", so sometimes you simply forget it.